# Should NSMutableParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore add space before paragraphs?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsimage, nsmutableparagraphstyle

Note: It appears that as of macOS Big Sur/11.6.4, this bug has been fixed. The test script now produces the second image instead of the third image when using `paragraphSpacingBefore`.

I’m writing a command-line script on macOS that creates an image from text. I want to give some paragraphs extra space *above*  to set them off from the previous paragraph. Due to the way the script works, it will be easier to set attributes on a paragraph that put extra space above it, rather than change the attributes on the previous paragraph. I thought this was what [paragraphSpacingBefore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1527729-paragraphspacingbefore) on `NSMutableParagraphStyle` is for.

However, while I can get paragraphSpacing to provide space *after* the first paragraph, paragraphSpacingBefore appears to add space after the *second* paragraph.

This very simplified test script will create an image with three paragraphs in it.

With both the `paragraphSpacing` line and the `paragraphSpacingBefore` line commented out, there is no extra spacing added between or around the paragraphs:

[image: no paragraph spacing]

If the `paragraphSpacing` line is uncommented, there is space between the three paragraphs:

[image: paragraphSpacing = 32]

But if the `paragraphSpacing` line is commented out and the `paragraphSpacingBefore` line is uncommented, there is no space between the three paragraphs but there is space added after the third paragraph:

[image: paragraphSpacingBefore = 32]

It appears that the spacing at the end is twice the paragraphSpacingBefore value; if I comment out the `cheers +=` line to make it only have two paragraphs, the space after the final paragraph looks to be about halved:

[image: two paragraphs, paragraphSpacingBefore = 32]

This doesn’t make sense to me. I would expect the third image (using `paragraphSpacingBefore` to be very similar to the second image. I am misunderstanding what `paragraphSpacingBefore` means, and/or I am doing something wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
//test paragraphSpacingBefore

import AppKit

//set up text
var cheers = "“What do you say, Norm?”\nAny cheap, tawdry thing that’ll get me a beer."
cheers += "\n—Cheers"

var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
//paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 32
paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 32
var textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle]
let textLines = NSAttributedString(string:cheers, attributes:textAttributes)

//create image of text
let outputSize = textLines.size()
let textRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
let background = NSColor(red:0, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1)

let outputImage = NSImage(size:outputSize, flipped: false) { (outputRect) -> Bool in
    //set a background color
    background.setFill()
    outputRect.fill()

    //draw the text
    textLines.draw(in: textRect)
    return true
}

//save image to file
var imageData = outputImage.tiffRepresentation
let bitmappedText = NSBitmapImageRep(data: imageData!)
imageData = bitmappedText!.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.png, properties:[:])
do {
    try imageData!.write(to: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "norm.png"))
} catch {
    print("Unable to save file.")
}
```

If `paragraphSpacingBefore` should put space above the second and third paragraphs, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce on Xcode playgrounds. If I comment `paragraphSpacing` and uncomment `paragraphSpacingBefore`, I get something similar to your second image, rather than the third.

Comment: But... if I run it in the terminal, it does produce your third image...

Comment: Ah, thanks. I’ve clarified that this is a command-line script on macOS. But nice to hear that what I want should, then, be possible.

Comment: I have also tried to create an Xcode project using the "command line tool" template, and the output executable created from works as intended in the command line. How about doing that instead?

Comment: That (Xcode makes it work) is helpful, too. But I would like to know what I’m doing wrong; and I’m not sure the feature is useful enough to forego being able to make quick changes and additions to the script.

Comment: Compiling in the command line with `swiftc` first, then running the executable works too... This seems to me like a bug in `/usr/bin/swift` (though it's hard to imagine how)... So for now, you can write another script that just does `swiftc YourScript.swift && ./YourScript` :)

Comment: Just tested on the bigger script this was distilled from. That (swiftc) is a very doable workaround until I figure out what's wrong/the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I observed, this behaviour only appears when you use the `swift` command:

```
swift YourScript.swift
```

If you instead run the code in an Xcode "Command Line Tool" project, or run the code in an Xcode playground, or compile the code with `swiftc`, *then* run it,

```
swiftc YourScript.swift && ./YourScript
```

`paragraphSpacingBefore` correctly puts the spacing in the right places.

I suspect that you might need to specify an option to `swift` for this to work, but I couldn't find a relevant option that is unique to `swift`.

So a workaround now is simply to write a new bash/zsh script that runs:

```
swiftc YourScript.swift && ./YourScript
```